# One Slick texture is blurry, one not

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

I want to bind two different textures to a cube using the Texture class of Slick.
The problem is that the first Texture I bind to the cube is shown correct, namely pixelwise but the other one I bind to the sides of the cube is blurred, as if I haven't entered

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

This is the code that renders the cube

```
    public void render(){
    float x = coordinate.x;
    float y = coordinate.y;
    float z = coordinate.z;

    top.bind();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        //TOP
        glNormal3f(0f, 1f, 0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
        glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f);
        glVertex3f(x, y, z+1);
        glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f);
        glVertex3f(x+1, y, z+1);
        glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);
        glVertex3f(x+1, y, z);
    glEnd();

    bottom.bind();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        //BOTTOM
        glNormal3f(0f, -1f, 0f);
        glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
        glVertex3f(x,y-1,z);
        glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f);
        glVertex3f(x, y-1, z+1);
        glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f);
        glVertex3f(x+1, y-1, z+1);
        glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);
        glVertex3f(x+1, y-1, z);
    glEnd();

    sides.bind();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        //BACK
        glNormal3f(0,0,-1);
        glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
        glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);
        glVertex3f(x+1, y, z);
        glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f);
        glVertex3f(x+1, y-1, z);
        glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f);
        glVertex3f(x, y-1, z);

        //FRONT
        glNormal3f(0,0,1);
        glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
        glVertex3f(x,y,z+1);
        glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);
        glVertex3f(x+1, y, z+1);
        glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f);
        glVertex3f(x+1, y-1, z+1);
        glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f);
        glVertex3f(x, y-1, z+1);

        //LEFT
        glNormal3f(-1,0,0);
        glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
        glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f);
        glVertex3f(x, y-1, z);
        glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f);
        glVertex3f(x, y-1, z+1);
        glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);
        glVertex3f(x, y, z+1);

        //RIGHT
        glNormal3f(1,0,0);
        glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
        glVertex3f(x+1,y,z);
        glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f);
        glVertex3f(x+1, y-1, z);
        glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f);
        glVertex3f(x+1, y-1, z+1);
        glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);
        glVertex3f(x+1, y, z+1);
    glEnd();

}
```

Comment: Do you call glTexParameteri for both textures?

Comment: Do I have to? Where should I call this? after loading the Textures?

Comment: Yes you need to for every texture. It is not a global setting. Do it after calling glBindTexture.

Answer (score 2):

If you want both textures to be "blurry" as you call it, you need to bind each texture individually, and call the following functions.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

If you them to be pixelated / "not blurry" you can call the following functions instead.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Remember that you need to call them individually, like this.

```
texture1.bind();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

texture2.bind();
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Comment: I think you have Nearest and Linear mixed up. Linear provides the "blurry" kind of effect, while nearest gives the pixelated effect.

Image filtering: http://slick.ninjacave.com/wiki/index.php?title=Image#Image_Filtering

Comment: @Samich Thanks for pointing that out, it was simply a typo from my part.